# Issue with JSON parser for android, which works well for java

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following json parsing code which works fine when tested as a java application. But on using it with in an android platform and running , returned the following  error

"Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0"

Here is my code

```
public boolean parseJSON(String content)  {

    boolean retvalue=false;
    String jsonString=null;
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    Object obj;
    try {
        System.out.println("in the parse json");
        obj = parser.parse(content);
        JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
        JSONObject obj2=(JSONObject)array.get(0);
        jsonString=(String) obj2.get("user_id");
        System.out.println("in the parse json  "+jsonString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (null != jsonString) {
        retvalue = true;
    }
    return retvalue;

}
```

The input string for the method is the following

[{"user_id":"1","username":"arvind","password":"somu","firstname":"Arvind somu","accountNumber":"1234567","lastname":"","address":"","email":"sample@gmail.com"}]

I have got the value  1  printed, when tried with java, but no idea why this issue is coming with android. Can   body suggest what is wrong with the code.The parser I am using is json-simple1.1.1

Comment: what is the issue any errors?

Comment: Try printing the `content` variable in the method before `parse(content)`.

Comment: yes, its in my question, "Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0" ,and the source is the line   obj = parser.parse(content); , but this problem is not coming  when tested in java

Comment: @dileepVikram try this `String userid= obj2.getString("user_id")`

Comment: @Raghunandan That didnt work, I think the issue is with the line
obj = parser.parse(content);  thnks for the quick response.

Comment: @dileepVikram what does it return `parser.parse(content)` are you using any other libraries to parse.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, I am using a jarfile json-simple or this purpose,I have got this from here  [basic links](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)

Comment: @dileepVikram for android you don't need those. I am not aware of that library or jar. sorry can't help further. but if you have your json string and you need to parse i canhelp

Comment: @Raghunandan then what should be the option,Please advise..

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes I have the json string with me, its given in the question.It is the following.
[{"user_id":"1","username":"arvind","password":"somu","firstname":"Arvind somu","accountNumber":"1234567","lastname":"","address":"","email":"arvind.somu@gmail.com"}]

Comment: @dileepVikram but i have not use the jar you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
   JSONObject obj2;
   obj2 = array.optJSONObject(0);
```

The method optJSONObject returns a JSONObject and you dont have to cast it, where as get() returns an Object. Try this i think this may solve it.